# Visual studio Emulator for Android not working

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create Xamarin android app, I can't run the Visual studio Emulator for Android, displayed the following error box, how can I fix it?
[image]
I tried to fix it using the following solution but didn't work

**1. Start Registry Editor.**

**2. Locate the following registry subkey:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization
```

**3. Right-click the Virtualization folder**

Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

**4. Type MemoryReserve, and then press Enter.**

**5. Double-click MemoryReserve,** enter 2048 in the Value data box, select the Decimal option, and then click OK.

**6. Close Registry Editor.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have probably **4 GB**s of **RAM** (also happened to me) so you will not be able to run the emulator. Solution would be buying more RAM :)

Minimum requirements for Visual Studio Android Emulator are following:

> System requirements
>
> - Hyper-V support (see Hyper-V requirements below)
> - **6 GB or more of RAM.**
> - 64-bit version of the Pro edition of Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows10 or higher
> - A processor that supports SSSE3 or later.
>
> Network requirements
>
> - DHCP
> - Automatically configured DNS and gateway settings
>
> Hyper-V requirements:
>
> - In the BIOS, the following features must be supported:
> - Hardware-assisted virtualization
> - Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
> - Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP)
> - In Windows, Hyper-V must be enabled and running.
> - You have to be a member of the local Hyper-V Administrators group.

**Source:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx

Comment: Thanks for it, yeah Actually i'll buy another ram for this, and im try it,

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error quite often when I'm running a large load of programs. I would recommend going into Task Manager, killing any larger processes and then running the emulator as one of the only processes(With VS of course).

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the solution, now Im try it, but not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Choose your device's cfg file]

Choose your device's cfg file 
and **change** this row device.vm.ram.size=2048 with **device.vm.ram.size=1024**